# Hold the type itself instead of instance in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, types

The `GridParser` and `PointParser` classes derive from `Parser` class. How can I hold they Types themselves inside the dictionary instead of an instance of them? Is it is even possible?

```
public class GridParser : Parser {}
public class PointParser: Parser {}
var _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    { 1 , GridParser },
    { 2 , PointParser }
};
```

Comment: I do not have the instances at this point.

Comment: Use `typeof()`. For example: `{ 1 , typeof(GridParser) },`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [typeof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator to get the object type and then store it in the dictionary.

```
public class GridParser : Parser {}
public class PointParser: Parser {}
var _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    { 1 , typeof(GridParser) },
    { 2 , typeof(PointParser) }
};
```

**UPDATE**
According to the question author comment below: after you have create the dictionary you want an instance from a Type you could use the [Activator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var t = _dictionary[0];
var some_var = (object)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
//Or dynamically
dynamic myDynVar = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Comment: I think I asked the question in a wrong way. I want to be able to store these classes in a dictionary and access them on demand and use their methods. But I do not see how it is possible with the above method. For example ´var t = _dictionary[1]; t.Create();´